# launcher minecraft error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

Minecraft won't run.  It was running perfectly until the 1.8.3 update.  The launcher is fine.  I tried older versions and that did not work.  I have a windows 8.1 HP laptop. all java has been downloaded. what am I doing wrong?  All the .minecraft folders are in order.  what do I do?

I have mods installed BUT they only open through the technic website and have their own folder
I would paste the launcher log but it is classed as spam  how do i fix this?? apparently it cannot find the specific file

```
[07:50:41 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.6.11 (through bootstrap 100) started on windows...
```

this is the launcher log I could paste

```
(try 0)
[07:50:54 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[07:50:54 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[07:50:54 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[07:50:54 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[07:50:54 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[07:50:54 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\twitch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-64.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[07:50:54 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[07:50:54 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[07:50:54 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[07:50:54 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[07:50:54 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[07:50:54 INFO]: Attempting to download core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar;C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main
[07:50:55 ERROR]: Couldn't launch game
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at com.mojang.launcher.game.process.direct.DirectGameProcessFactory.startGame(DirectGameProcessFactory.java:14) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.11]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.game.MinecraftGameRunner.launchGame(MinecraftGameRunner.java:208) [launcher.jar:1.6.11]
    at com.mojang.launcher.game.runner.AbstractGameRunner.onDownloadJobFinished(AbstractGameRunner.java:186) [launcher.jar:1.6.11]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:122) [launcher.jar:1.6.11]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:1.6.11]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:86) [launcher.jar:1.6.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    ... 12 more
[07:50:55 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3-natives-1876989825718
```

Answer (score 2):

## The culprit

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is Windows saying that it cannot execute a file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe` because it cannot find such a file.  The most likely cause is that the file does not exist.

Verify that your Minecraft profile points to the Java installation you want to use.  Since you appear to be running a 64-bit OS, you may want to run a 64-bit version of Java for overall better performance.

## But I installed Java, more than once even!

> all java has been downloaded

[Out of security concerns](http://java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml), Oracle's Java installers *may* opt to remove versions of Java that are outdated or end-of-life.  If you've installed version 8 *after* you installed version 7, the former may have removed the latter (though it should ask you whether you want to remove older versions).

The easiest way to keep an older Java (JRE) installed, if you need to, is to **install the highest version first**.  Older versions will not remove newer versions.

Comment: i have the latest 64 bit java, is that bad? im using the new minecraft luncher as well. aslso i checked the .minecraft folder and found the launcher file

Comment: @shadowspawn Programs in "Program Files (x86)" (including Java) are 32-bit.  If you installed 64-bit Java 8 to its default path, it should be in "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8".  Note the lack of "(x86)".

Answer (score 1):

If you have any JVM arguments typed in your profile settings, you may want to uncheck them. It just fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

> This is Windows saying that it cannot execute a file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe because it cannot find such a file. The most likely cause is that the file does not exist.

Verify that your Minecraft profile points to the Java installation you want to use. Since you appear to be running a 64-bit OS, you may want to run a 64-bit version of Java for overall better performance.

This problem can most likely be solved by using Mojang's new Minecraft installer. Mojang's installer will actually install Minecraft to your `C:\Program Files (x86)` folder. Not only that, the new launcher no longer needs Java to run, as it installs it's own custom JRE made just for Minecraft, that can also boost you FPS. [Try out this new launcher](https://minecraft.net/download), and tell me if it solves your problem.

You have said you installed the new launcher, but according to the crash log, the Minecraft launcher is still using the old Java executable which is goofing it up a bit. Try uninstalling Java, and uninstalling Minecraft. After you do this, reinstall Minecraft and see what happens.

Comment: i have the minecraft launcher andf all filrs are present